# jquery-mobile: fieldcontain with small textbox

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using a `<div data-role='fieldcontain'>` to make a "box" where there are two fields "min" and "max" the problem is that I want to have two parts in the same line, but jquery mobile separes in two lines if display width is smaller than size jquery wants. I try to put width of two components, but it still separes in two lines and the label and text box are smaller than half display...

this is my code:

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain' id='TempLimits'>
<label for='Tmin' style='display-inline;width:100;'>Min
<input type='text' name='Tmin' id='Tmin' value='50' disabled='disabled' style='display:inline;width:50px;'/></div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: How about using a `controlgroup` widget? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html

Comment: It's not buttons block, it's three lines with a label+input in each line...

Comment: I solved it changing display:inline to display:inline-block;  Now all is working well

Comment: please add your solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain' id='TempLimits'>
<label for='Tmin' style='display-inline;width:100;'>Min
<input type='text' name='Tmin' id='Tmin' value='50' disabled='disabled' style='display:inline-block;width:50px;'/></div>
```

Comment: What did you change? Can you emphasize the relevant part a little more?

Comment: I don't know how to emphasize inside code block, as I told above, I change **display:inline** to **display:inline-block** inside the input type